# How to avoid loss Focusing of TextBox in UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

What I have tried?

```
<Grid >
    <Canvas>
        <Canvas x:Name="Gesture" Width="500" Height="500" Background="Gray" AllowFocusOnInteraction="False">
            
        </Canvas>
        <StackPanel x:Name="SidePanel" Canvas.Left="500" Background="LightCyan" Width="100" Height="500">
            <TextBox x:Name="NameBox" Text="Prem" Width="100" Height="35"/>
            <Button Content="But" AllowFocusOnInteraction="False"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

What I need to achieve?

While the Textbox got focus, if I click on Button it won't loss focus. Because, I set the Button property - AllowFocusOnInteraction="False".

I need to achieve the same, when I click inside the Gray area(Gesture Canvas).I have set the Canvas Property-AllowFocusOnInteraction="False". But it won't work.

The textbox should be focused when I Click inside the Gesture canvas. How to Do it? Why AllowFocusOnInteraction won't work on Gesture Canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the focus states in the `LostFocus` event to make sure your TextBox won't lose focus.

You could handle the LostFocus event of the **TextBox** and the Tapped event of the **StackPanel**. Then when the **StackPanel** is clicked, change the flag value and set the focus state in the `LostFocus` event

```
 <StackPanel x:Name="SidePanel" Canvas.Left="500" Background="LightCyan" Width="100" Height="500" Tapped="SidePanel_Tapped">
            <TextBox x:Name="NameBox" Text="Prem" Width="100" Height="35" LostFocus="NameBox_LostFocus"/>
            <Button Content="But" AllowFocusOnInteraction="False"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

Code behind

```
private bool setFocus = true;

 private void NameBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (setFocus == true)
        {
            NameBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
        }
    }

    private void SidePanel_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        setFocus = true;
    }
```

Comment: Is tapped event always fired before the Lost Focus event?

Comment: @PremKumarShanmugam Yes, the tapped event fires before the lost focus event